# Read UISlider Value inside a Subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I read the value of my UISlider inside my SubView? I've tried the following but I get the error property 'slider not found' on object of type UIView? Thanks in advance.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property UIView *controlview;
@property UISlider *slider;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIView *controlview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,                 self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height/4))];
    controlview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   [self.view addSubview:controlview];
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 40.0);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 25.0;
    [controlview addSubview:slider];
 }

 - (void)sliderAction 
 {
    float slidervalue = [_controlview.slider.value];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(slidervalue, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 480);
    NSLog(@"YES");
 }

@end
```

Comment: You're not assigning the slider added to your view to the global slider property!

Comment: @Paul Thomas Balfour - you should take the time to accept answers. You'll get more of a response.

Comment: @Woodstock apologies to all concerned. My genuine mistake. I'd omitted to accept any of the answers to my questions. Will try better next time. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @PaulThomasBalfour no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider is a property of your class, simply read it's value by calling self.slider.value like so:

```
float slidervalue = self.slider.value;
```

Also change this:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

to this:

```
self.slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made two property in your code that has no use, because you are adding objects locally.

**`Problem`**  Because slider is a local object in your code. You can not access slider object outside the method it is defined in.

**`Solution`**    Change this lines in your code

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And change method to this

```
- (void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
   UISlider *mySlider = (UISlider*)sender; 
   float slidervalue = mySlider.value;
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(slidervalue, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 480);
}
```